# Propel - propel:build-sql - Ability to add CREATE DATABASE .. IF NOT EXISTS

Tags: mysql, orm, propel

I'm customizing a phpUnderControl build file to use the `symfony propel:build-sql` functionality to generate .sql files to be loaded for every build (not every test). What I am running into is that the resulting .sql files expect the databases to exist, but as part of the build process, I would like to drop and recreate every database found in the schema.yml file to ensure a clean testing environment.

My question is, is it possible to configure propel:build-sql to behave as though I passed the --add-drop-database [mysqldump flag?](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_add-drop-database)

Comment: propel:build --sql adds `drop table if exists` statements for every tables in the DB.

Comment: Looking for the `drop database if exists`. As you stated the `drop table if exists` statements are already present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it's not possible. It's your job to drop/create the database before you run symfony/propel commands.

Comment: I'm afraid your right. Had to create a bash script to drop/create databases based on the names of the data/sql/*.sql files after doing a `symfony propel:build-sql` command.